# How gradle dependencies map in my java project

Tags: java, gradle

In my gradle project file I have added my dependency as follows

```
dependencies {

   compile project(":aerobuy:aerobuy-api-ejb")

}
```

I know that the compiled jars will be stores under .gradle folder under my username

But how can this dependencies going to be map into my current projects ,Which is under the .gradle folder,will there be a xml file kind of things automatically generated to map these dependencies?

Comment: This is a dependency to another project in the same reactor (multi project build). The file is stored in the sister project directory not in the `.gradle` folder.

Comment: I need to know how these dependency references going to map in my project ,
Normally if there are any xml files generated defining these references  ,it makes sense how its going to handle those dependencies. But I don't seen any of them generated.

Comment: Not clear what you mean, The full pathname of the dependency's `.jar` file is put onto the compile classpath.by gradle.